# Cannot create agent via dialogflow console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've spent more than an hour on the GCP console and cannot figure out how to create an agent. I created a project, a service account, enabled the dialogflow sdk. I even started my free trial just in case billing was required. I'm only interested in testing capabilities with the standard edition.

The quick start guide says to "Click Create Agent in the left sidebar menu". I do not have that option. My left hand menu under Dialogflow API has: Overview, Metrics, Quotas, Credentials. Can anyone provide the navigation path to actually using dialogflow via the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login via your gmail account https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/#/login

[Create an agent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/build-agent#create-an-agent)
The steps in this guide make assumptions about your agent, so it's best to start with a new agent. You should delete any existing agent for your project before creating a new one. To delete an existing agent:

1. Go to the Dialogflow Console.
2. If requested, sign in to the Dialogflow Console. See Dialogflow console overview for more information.
3. Select the agent you wish to delete.
4. Click the settings button next to the agent's name.
5. Scroll down to the bottom of the General settings tab.
6. Click Delete this agent.
7. Enter DELETE in the text field.
8. Click Delete.

To create an agent:

1. Go to the Dialogflow Console.
2. If requested, sign in to the Dialogflow Console. See Dialogflow console overview for more information.
3. Click Create Agent in the left sidebar menu. (If you already have other agents, click the agent name, scroll to the bottom and click Create new agent.)
4. Enter your agent's name, default language, and default time zone.
5. If you have already created a project, enter that project. If you want to allow the Dialogflow Console to create the project, select Create a new Google project.
6. Click the Create button.

Comment: I see. It's not possible to navigate to the console from the same space where you create a project.